# Add RAM to Lenovo Thinkpad E450

Tags: memory, thinkpad

Good day.

A laptop computer, Lenovo Thinkpad E450. It has 8G RAM. I want add RAM to at least 16G.

Without knowing if it has empty RAM slot inside, and which type/model RAM stick I shall buy.

What's the steps and procedure that I can succeed in this little upgrade project?

Thank you.

Comment: Either look in the BIOS or open it and see. You're going to have to do it anyway to get to 16GB either by adding another 8GB DIMM or by replacing the two 4GB DIMMS with two 8GB DIMMS.

Comment: @NasirRiley,   Thank you for the comment. Is there a program/app, I can see the model, number of RAM,  If empty slot, of the laptop?

Comment: Have you tried using Google to look for one?

Comment: I was hoping somebody to share the entire experience, from checking, buy, open the machine, install, and cover it back up, in not very complicated steps. (•̀⌄•́)

Comment: From what I found online, you have two slots on this machine, both with removable sticks, a rarity these days, and you can max it out to 16GB, hence 2x8GB. I found this, but that's just one vendor, and I don't wish to promote their services over anyone else's, but they sell kits for most of the PC out there, so it's safe to assume you can do it yourself: https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/lenovo/thinkpad-e450

Comment: @Didier, Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Found a step by step guide with explanations and pictures, if somebody finds it is convenient, https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/ram-upgrade-tutorial.

My key concern were 1. if the laptop has empty ram slot, and 2. what model of ram I should buy.

Here are the sample apps that can address above.

The left hand is info from Crucial's Memory Advisor tool, which may recommend the suitable model.

The right one is CPU-Z, bottom line shows the voltage (1.5V is DDR3 standard, 1.35V is DDR3L, low voltage)

[image]

Comment: Link-only answers are prone to link rot and can become useless in the future. Please put relevant info in the answer so that it's self-contained and then link to original source.

Comment: @gronostaj, Thank you thank you for the comment. I added some info.